# How to align textbox and button horizontally using bootstrap-3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem on how to align a text box and a submit button horizontally using bootstrap 4, 
I've tried some solution such as d-flex, d-inline-flex and doesn't work.

Below are the expected output and the actual position of the text-box and submit button.

Expected output:

```
<textbox><submit button>
```

Actuals:

```
<textbox>
<submit button>
```

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-inline-flex padding col-md-6">
    <form>
        <input class="form-control form-control-md ml-3 active-blue" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <input class="btn btn-secondary form-control-md" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks you in advance! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer on stackoverflow and is says the solution is

Please see the html code below,

```
<div class="container groug-from col-md-7">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control col-md-10 text-size-7" type="text" placeholder="Find something here">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Search" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

In order to make it horizontal I have to add this class selector in bootstrap called: **form-group**.

This is contained inside a  tag having a class selector in bootstrap called: **form-inline**